# Inserting in SQLite with ContentValues in for loop

Tags: nullpointerexception, android-sqlite, content-values

I am trying to add multiple records in SQLite with for loop likewise, but data is not fetched while calling from function and getting null pointer exception:

```
ContentValues[] ans7 = new ContentValues[4];
    for(int j =0; j<4; j++){
        ans7[j] = new ContentValues();
        ans7[j].put(KEY_ANSWER, Utils.DB_NULL_INT_VALUE);
        ans7[j].put(KEY_TYPE, Utils.TYPE_NORMAL);
        ans7[j].put(KEY_RESOURCE, ans7Array[j]);
        if(j==1) {
            ans7[j].put(KEY_IS_CORRECT, Utils.CORRECT);
        }else{
            ans7[j].put(KEY_IS_CORRECT, Utils.INCORRECT);
        }
        ans7[j].put(KEY_QUESTION_ID, 7);
        long i = db.insert(TABLE_ANSWER, null, ans7[j]);
        Log.e("Answer type 3", "que 7 " + i);
    }
```

I don't know whether it is if-else clause which causing it.

Answer (score 0):

The if-else inside is working. 
My mistake. Null pointer exception was for another reason.